# Play!Framework 1.2.3 VS IIS 7.5 + ASP.Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, playframework, benchmarking

Hi I am a little bit to say that my little benchmark test shows Play's performance cannot match .net, at least in my little laptop. Here is the details:

Play Code

```
// Controller
public class Benchmark extends Controller {
    @CacheFor
    public static void hello() {
        String who = "world";
        render(who);
    }
}
// View
hello ${who}!
```

ASP.Net code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Benchmark.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>Hello <span id="spnName" runat="server"></span></p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;

namespace Benchmark {
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            spnName.InnerText = "world";
        }
    }
}
```

benchmark tool: ab, running on the same machine:

```
`ab -n 10000 -c 100 http://localhost/`
```

Play result:

```
Server Software:        Play!
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        13 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.839 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      3650000 bytes
HTML transferred:       130000 bytes
Requests per second:    2066.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       48.393 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.484 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          736.57 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.5      0       7
Processing:     5   48   7.0     45      79
Waiting:        2   33  11.3     34      74
Total:          5   48   7.1     45      80

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     45
  66%     47
  75%     49
  80%     53
  90%     58
  95%     62
  98%     69
  99%     72
 100%     80 (longest request)
```

asp.net result:

```
Server Software:        Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        5160 bytes

Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   3.806 seconds
Complete requests:      10000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      10000
Total transferred:      53780000 bytes
HTML transferred:       51600000 bytes
Requests per second:    2627.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       38.062 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.381 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          13798.35 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.4      0       2
Processing:     6   38   3.8     37      61
Waiting:        4   27   7.6     28      57
Total:          6   38   3.8     37      61

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     37
  66%     38
  75%     39
  80%     40
  90%     43
  95%     44
  98%     48
  99%     51
 100%     61 (longest request)
```

Notes:

1. IIS warm up very quickly, run the benchmark test 2 times to reach it's peak performance; while it take about 4 or 5 times for Play to reach it's limitation.
2. play is started in prod mode.
3. changing concurrent setting of ab doesn't impact the result 2 much. IIS always out perform play.
4. the configuration of my machine: windows 7 (32bit) on HP 4720s, CPU: i5 M 430 2.27GHz 4 core; memory 4GB

So I am a little bit frustrated as I am a huge play fan and worked on this platform for over 2 years. Does anyone know any way to improve the performance of Play?

Comment: HAve you set play.pool = nb proc + 1 in you application.conf

Comment: I find it interesting to compare your results with my results (https://github.com/mbknor/template_benchmark_app/blob/master/template_benchmark.txt). On my macbook pro i7, I have a lot more throughput than you. (I know I have different hardware and different ab params. more info here: http://kjetland.com/blog/2011/11/playframework-new-faster-groovy-template-engine/

Comment: Anyone else think it would also be a damn shame if *Windows-native compiled code* would run any slower than this on a *Windows* platform using *Microsoft's IIS* server? ;-)

Comment: for an empty hello world app in my dev i7 laptop, I've seen 4K reqs/sec with asp.net mvc 4/razor/iis/windows 7/release mode, 9K reqs/sec with Mint Linux/Apache/Play 2.0/Scala, 17K reqs/sec with Mint Linux/Nginx/Play 2.0/Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are my experiences;

1. Play is working on linux/ngix or linux/apache much faster than on windows/iis
2. the problem with play 1.2.x is it's groovy (dynamic) rendering engine; so I recommend play 2 for performance and low memory usage. As you know play 2's template engine is based on static compiled scala code and I can say play 2 is the fastest web framework I've ever seen.

Comment: Again there is nothing about groovy template in this benchmark test. See my comments in respond to @mbknor below. I might accept that Play is working on linux/nginx point. But needs verification.

Comment: the difference with play 1.2.x and 2.0 is not only the template system, but also there is static routing, better concurrency with akka and much more. Also take a look at this benchmark. http://www.jtict.com/blog/rails-wicket-grails-play-lift-jsp/

In this benchmark as you can see play 1.2.1 groovy is slower than some frameworks (some rails variations and groovy..) but play 1.2 with japid or scala module is the fastest of all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the poor performance of the default groovy template support in play 1.

In Play 2, there is a faster scala-based template engine.

For Play 1 there is a number of other template systems implemented, ie: Japid i think.

Also: There exists a faster groovy template engine implementation for play 1 which you can find info about here: http://kjetland.com/blog/2011/11/playframework-new-faster-groovy-template-engine/

Comment: It's not true. 1. the view is too simple. 2. the request is cached for 1 hour, except the 1st request all other requests returned from cache instead of invoking groovy view rendering.

Comment: agree.. the rendering is only executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Many times we see "hypes" around framework and the only way to find the truth was testing by your own or look for professional benchmark. I suggest you to check the benchmark result "http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r8&hw=i7&test=query". You would be surprised to know that old fashioned "java servlet-raw" was among the TOP performance framework list, ignoring the buzzwords around "Non-Blocking", Scala, NodeJS.

Play2 may have better performance compared to Play1, but "low memory usage" was definitely NOT TRUTH. Running bootstrap Play1 app consumes only 50m memory, running bootstrap Play2 app could easily consume more than 300m.